# Перевод числа из десятичной с\с в двоичную с\с

Tags: java

Задачка, написать метод перевода числа из десятичной сс в двоичную сс.

```
public class Binary {  
    public static void binar(int a) {  
        int i, b;   
        while(a !=0 ) {  
            b = a%2;  
            System.out.print(b);  
            a = a/2;  
        }  
    }    
    public static void main(String [] args) {  
        binar(8);  
    }  
}
```

Вопрос: почему число на печать выводит в обратном порядке? Кто-нибудь может подсказать?

Comment: А не проще сначала посчитать а потом вывести? Или задача именно в выводе? Если в выводе то можно сразу в строку забивать в нужной последовательности а потом вывести.

Comment: вот само задание:
    Write a method that receives an integer in base ten and returns out the original number represented in base 2.
For example, giving 8 will return "1000".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Потому, что попробуйте решить задачу вручную и сразу все поймете.

```
b = 8 % 2 = 0
b = 4 % 2 = 0
b = 2 % 2 = 0
b = 1 % 2 = 1
```

И вы соответственно последовательно это выводите.
Как решение проблемы, пишите все в строку (StringBuilder), а затем переверните ее.

Comment: Только пишите в StringBuilder, а не напрямую в строку.

Comment: Логично:) Поправил

Comment: Не подумал о таком раскладе =) благодарю за подсказку ;)

Answer (score 3):

Вот решение без использования String`а

```
 public static void binar(int n) {
    int i = bitsInNumber(n);
    int bit;
    while ( --i >= 0 ){
        bit = (n & (1 << i)) == 0 ? 0 : 1;
        System.out.print(bit);
    }
}

public static int bitsInNumber(int n) {
    int res = 0;
    while (n > 0) {
        n >>= 1;
        res++;
    }
    return res;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

кхэм. Может так?

```
int a = 290;
System.out.println(Integer.toString(a, 2));
```

или так

```
public static String toBinaryString(int i) {
    return toUnsignedString(i, 1);
}
```

Comment: У автора как раз цель: "написать метод перевода числа из десятичной сс в двоичную сс". Конечно, при реальной разработке стоит воспользоваться готовым решением.

Comment: public static String binar(int a) { return Integer.toString(a, 2); } - условие выполнено

Answer (score 1):

Решение таки  было найдено =)

```
public class Binary {   
         public static void binar(int a){    
                int b;     
            String temp = "";    
                while(a !=0){  
                b = a%2;  
                temp = b + temp;  
                a = a/2;  
           } System.out.print(temp);  
        }  
        public static void main(String [] args) {  
  binar(5);  
 }  
}
```

Comment: если вашей задачей было вывести бинарное представление строки в целях "сдать лабу" то  да. во всех других случаях советую обратить внимание на ответ @Антон-Феоктистов

Comment: Задача преведена комментарием выше ;)
В данном случае целью стояло применить полученные знания на практике, к тому же, вопрос был несколько иным, не подсказывать решение, а подсказать почему происходит определённое действие; за предоставленное оптимальное решение конечно спасибо! (Буду иметь ввиду его в будущем) =)

Answer (score 0):

Еще можно как-то так

```
public class Example {

    public static String iterateBinarConv(int number) {
            if (number < 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Number < 0");
            if (number == 0) return "0";

            /*вычисляем длинну массива для буф.*/
            int index = (int) Math.ceil(
                    Math.log(number) / Math.log(2)
            ) + 1;

            char[] buf = new char[index];

            int innerIndex = index - 1;
            while (number != 0) {
                buf[innerIndex--] = (char) ((number % 2) + 30);
                number/=2;
            }

            return new String(buf);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
package bin;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Binar {   
    public static void binar(int a){    
    int b;     
    String temp = "";    
    while(a !=0){  
        b = a%2;  
        temp = b + temp;  
        a = a/2;  
    } if (temp.equals("10")) {
        temp = "0" + temp;
        System.out.println(temp);  }
    if (temp.equals("11")) {
        temp = "0" + temp; 
        System.out.println(temp); }
    if (temp.equals("1")) {
        temp = "00" + temp;
        System.out.println(temp); } else {
            System.out.println(temp);
        }
}  
public static  void binarturn(String [] args) {  
    Scanner kb = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.print("Введите число которое хотите перевести в (Двоичное) - ");
    int  c =  kb.nextInt();  
    binar(c);
    kb.close();
}

}
```

А еще вот модификация на основе взятого кода, без метода main и подготовленного для импорта в другие классы... собственно весь класс является методом. Развилка if добавлена для того что бы при переводе 1,2,3 мы получали "001", "010", "011" а не 1,10,11...
А теперь у меня возникла идея, что бы после вызова данного метода в другом классе можно было в том же классе сохранить выдаваемое значение из тела текущего метода а именно "temp"... но как реализовать это я пока не могу придумать) есть идеи?

Comment: Не задавайте никаких новых вопросов. Вы дали ответ, и он должен содержать только конкретный ответ на вопрос в этом топике.